# get class name using Throwable

Tags: java

Why does this code allows to get class name?

I declare a class with static method (it is not neccessary need to be static BTW)

```
class JavaSample {
    public static String getClassName() {
        final Throwable t = new Throwable();
        t.fillInStackTrace();
        final String clazz = t.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

And if I then write

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(JavaSample.getClassName());
     }
}
```

It returns `HelloWorld` class name. But if I do like this

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        final Throwable t = new Throwable();
        t.fillInStackTrace();
        final String clazz = t.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
        System.out.println(clazz);
     }
}
```

It throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in line `t.getStackTrace()[1]`.

Why it returns classname when I use `Throwable`?

Comment: I guess it's because you actually don't have a callstack? The main execution is already on a base level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version works because `t.getStackTrace()` returns an array where the first element (element 0) is the current method (`JavaSample.getClassName`) and the second element (element 1) is the caller (`HelloWorld.main`). In the second version, you don't have a caller, and the stack trace contains only one element (element 0), hence you get an exception when referring to the non-existent element 1.

There is no need to create a `Throwable` just to get the stack trace. You can get it by calling `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the stack trace contains the function getClassName() and main(). In the second case there is only main(), therefore the stack trace contains only one entry and t.getStackTrace()[1] raises an error.